# How to delete line from CSV as they are read in Bash

Tags: bash, readline

I am currently doing this:

```
while read l
do
  echo git add $l/
  git add $l/
  # sed -i -e '1,1d' data/commit-folders.csv
  # echo git commit -am "'Autocommit'"
  # git commit -uno -am "'Autocommit'"
  # echo git push origin master
  # git push origin master
done < data/commit-folders.csv
```

Essentially just `git add <folder>` for a list of folders in a CSV file. I would like for this to be more robust, in that every time it restarts it restarts from where it left off. So I added that commented out line which does an in-place delete `sed -i -e '1,1d' data/commit-folders.csv`. However, with `while read line`, it messes up with the current line if they are being deleted. So I'm wondering how to do this properly.

How to iterate through a CSV file with `<path>` on each line, and delete the path once it is successfully git added. It seems like you need to have a loop that selects the first line from a file, and then deletes it from the file afterwards, rather than using `while read line`.

Comment: Also, I am dynamically writing to `data/commit-folders.csv` as it is being deleted from, so it should be able to handle that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the loop will alwaus process all lines in the csv file unless you interrupt the script. The interrupt may occur anywhere in the loop, so you can't be sure if the interrupt happens before or after updating the csv file? If you write handled lines to some extra log file, you cant be sure when the interrupt happens either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution without sed.

```
#!/bin/bash
csv="data/commit-folders.csv"
done="$(mktemp)"

# autoremove tempfile at exit
trap 'rm "$done"' EXIT

# loop over all lines in csv
while read -r file; do
   printf "git add %s\n" "$file"
   git add "$file"

   # write processed files in tempfile
   printf "%s\n" "$file" >> "$done"

   #...
done < "$csv"

# create tempfile for merge result
newfile="$(mktemp)"

# sort: merge and sort $cvs with $done
# uniq -u: write only unique files into tempfile
sort "$csv" "$done" | uniq -u > "$newfile" 

# override $csv with tempfile
mv "$newfile" "$csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sed -i "/${l}/d"` , it will find the exact line and delete it. This assumes that there would be no duplicate lines.

```
while read l
do
  echo git add $l/
  git add $l/
  # sed -i -e '1,1d' data/commit-folders.csv
  sed -i "/${l}/d" data/commit-folders.csv
  # echo git commit -am "'Autocommit'"
  # git commit -uno -am "'Autocommit'"
  # echo git push origin master
  # git push origin master
done < data/commit-folders.csv
```

Comment: `sed: 1: "/foo/10/30/0/d": extra characters at the end of n command` how to fix the fact that `<path>` is multiple slashes with sed.

Comment: Use `sed "|${l}|d"`  , use pipe or @ or # instead of / in sed command. As your lines already contains /.